# Android: Show Interstitial Ad after user pressed notification

Tags: android, ads

Currently in my application when user presses notification an Activity is shown, what I want to do is to add Google Interstitial Ad in between (after user pressed notification and before the activity is shown). The problem is that it may take time for the ad to load. What would be the best approach to implement this?

Comment: I'd reconsider the approach completely. If I tap a notification, I'd expect to be taken to a place where I can interact with that notification. If an ad pops up instead, I will guarantee that the next activity on my screen will be app settings/uninstall.

Comment: Totally agree, explained the issue to the client - still a requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

Preload the ad when application is started to reduce the ad loading time.

But generally there is no magic solution. If the add takes time to load, give it that time, show a progress bar while it is loading. And only after the user interacted with the add, move to next activity.

Comment: Hi Ilya, in my case the application is a background service that is scheduled to run at specific time and leave notification after is was finished, so I don't think there is a place  where I could preload the ad and its part of the problem. There is no GUI shown till the notification is pressed

Comment: @user3524517 GUI after the notification is pressed